# Why does my conditional formatting not work with this formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Below is a formula I want to use in conditional formatting. Its purpose is to blur a range in a text concatenation table if a checkbox B15 is unchecked and if the left and right of the string matches any value from `'Code Sheet'!X4:AD4 (m, ɱ,  n,  ɳ,  ɲ,  ŋ, or   ɴ)`.

```
=iferror(and($B$15=false, 
if(match(left(C19,1),{'Code Sheet'!X4:AD4},0),
if(match(right(C19,1),{'Code Sheet'!X4:AD4},0),
true,false))),false)
```

The conditional formatting should blur any combo of the aforementioned values. But my formula does not work outside of a cell. The conditional formatting box turns red without feedback. I have no idea why. Where am I going wrong?

Note: the concatenation table has the range of `C19:CH102`, and the table filters and transposes values - meaning the formula must also adapt to changes in data position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `indirect()` when referring to another sheet in a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule, like this:

`=not($B$15) * ifna(match(left(C19), indirect("Code Sheet!X4:AD4"), 0)) * ifna(match(right(C19), indirect("Code Sheet!X4:AD4"), 0))`

The formula will only return a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value when all three conditions are met. To use an "or" condition that returns a truthy value when *any* of the conditions is met, replace the `*` with `+`. To always require the first condition, but accept either of the two following conditions, use *first* `*` `(` *second* `+` *third* `)`. See [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra).

Comment: Your suggested formula seems to be multiplying values. When I tested it on a cell where the conditions would fail, 0 was the output. When I tested it on a cell where conditions were met, 6 was the output.

Comment: That is correct. Any non-zero number will be considered truthy, i.e., interpreted as `true`, in a conditional formatting custom formula rule.

Comment: Ok. But the conditional formatting box is still angry, saying "invalid formula".

Comment: Look on the sheet labeled "Phonotactics Calculator." https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qgmw7QKeStLaEdzYewSxWDd7gR-verVMd_i-ESxqw28/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Edited the answer. There are currently no values in your sample spreadsheet that would meet the conditions because the checkbox in `B15` is ticked. Untick it to find a cluster of matching cells at `V38:AB44`.